# Is installation only copying some files in some specific folders?

Tags: software-installation, compiling, configuration, c++, opencv

I am interested to know when I install something like `opencv` for example, it just copies some files/folders in some folders/directories like `usr/local/include` or `usr/local/lib`? Or maybe some extra things will happens and it changes content of some files in my computer as configurations?

Also, I like to know, if I want to change a function of `opencv`, should I go and find the file this function is defined within(the related `.cpp` file) then modify the function? There is no extra steps needed like compiling again or changing some configurations by hand?

Comment: it depends of what you mean by installation, for example using packages (rpm or deb) anything could happen, from copying/replacing/removing files to simply deploy a shell script to modifying config files. it will depend of so many factor, if you're using a `make` file to install your application then you should read the part where the install process is declare so you know what is done.

Answer (score 1):

Installing a package from a distribution is usually nothing more than copying files to specific locations and updating the package manager's database, though some packages may have hooks attached (scripts that run pre- or post-installation).

For libraries, this is generally a collection of `.h` files in a typical include directory, and `.so` or `.a` files in a library directory. These libraries are the output of a compilation run, and most of the time the source files (`.c`, `.cpp`, etc) are not included.

If you want to make changes to a library (or any compiled executable code), you need to obtain these sources, modify them to fit your needs, then recompile.  If you repackage the output in a way suitable for your distribution, you can install the changes with your package manager.